# UITableViewCell.frame of newly inserted row

Tags: ios, uitableview, insert, frame

In my app there is a view with text fields, which serves as a form for adding a new record to a table view. After tapping the Save button I want the form view to animate with a zoom-in effect into a row newly inserted into the table view. Because inserted cell can be below the screen, table is scrolled until the new cell is insight.

How can I read a frame of newly inserted raw?

My present code looks like follows:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                            animated:YES
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

zoomInFrame = [self.tableView convertRect:[self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                                   toView:self.parentViewController.view];
```

however zoomInFrame does not store the correct data.

Where should I search the right frame for?

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you the frame of the particular cell with indexPath:

// Get the cell rect and adjust it to consider scroll offset

```
CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cellRect = CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x - tableView.contentOffset.x, cellRect.origin.y - tableView.contentOffset.y, cellRect.size.width, cellRect.size.height);
```